# jQuery push text from inside / outside of brackets to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use json save for a template builder. And I convert some blocks and html tables into simple tags, eg: `[[TableName(Title,SKU,Total)]]`

The code for this tag looks like this:

```
<div class="box table">    
    <table id="TableName">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">Title</td>
                <td class="sku">SKU</td>
                <td class="total">Total</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="title"></td>
                <td class="sku"></td>
                <td class="total"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

On load, I need to convert tag back to html, so I use:

```
var tag = []
template.find('.table').each(function(){
    var array = $(this).html().match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].split(',');
    tag.push(array);
});
console.log(tag)
```

but I need to get the id too "TableName" than generate the table.

Comment: Is the id 'TableName' to be an element in the array or should the result  be the exact same format as ``[[TableName(Title,SKU,Total)]]``

Comment: no need to be into array, I just need to extract it for ID

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need simpler templating engine :
You can try handlebarjs. It's very easy to use and have good performance.

http://handlebarsjs.com/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HuAnM6b2d8

Comment: there are alot of this (moustache, etc..), but I'm not using that many tags to include a new library

Answer (score 0):

```
var $tableID = $(".table").attr("id"); // gets the table's id
var tag = []
template.find('.table').each(function(){
    var array = $(this).html().match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].split(',');
    tag.push(array);
});
console.log(tag)
```

Comment: I don't have the HTML, only the TAG - so I need to extract it from there

Comment: Your post says "jQuery", it's tagged with jQuery - I provided a jQuery answer.

Comment: you didn't understand what I need! On load I get json with multiple tags like in my example. So no html. After load, I need to replace all tags into html. So How do i get the ID "with jQuery" as you said, if I don't have the html? Need to get the ID from same TAG

Comment: What you `need` is some semi-colons on the ends of those lines of code, better communication skills and to show your attempts at the problem.